# Single Sign on (SSO) implementation

Tags: single-sign-on

We have multiple web application some build In house and some by third part.
Most of the applications are built on .net and we have windows setup available here Like windows server, Active directory. We want to implement single sign on in this conditions. So that there is only one entry point into the system

1. If my all applications are based on .net
2. If There are some applications on Java or other language.
3. To implement SSO in third party software we can ask them to update the software for SSO integration

My workflow is given in screen shot[image]